# How do I install the experimental Nvidia open-source drivers?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, nvidia

During the Ubuntu 11.10 beta 1 there were experimental Nvidia open source drivers.
I liked them a lot more than the proprietary ones because they let me use the native dual-screen settings from Ubuntu, instead of Nvidias ones which trick Ubuntu into thinking I have one massive screen instead of two regular ones.

They were removed from the final release (I think).

Does anyone know what i'm talking about and whether there is a way to get them back?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau libdrm-nouveau1a nouveau-firmware
```

It should install the driver.

Comment: The Nvidia driver is still present. Is there anyway to check if it has installed this open source one properly?

Comment: If you want to remove the closed-source nVidia driver, try this: `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current`